# Numpy.nonzero behaves strangely for values 1 or -1

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have a very odd problem with numpy.nonzero(). It behaves well for values that are not 1 or -1, but for those two it seems to yield odd results.

For example,

```
goalmat = np.matrix( [[2, 0, 1], [-1, 0, -1]])
```

makes

```
matrix([[ 2,  0,  1],
        [-1,  0, -1]])
```

Now, using numpy.nonzero(goalmat == x) only works partially:

```
>>> np.nonzero(goalmat == 1)
(matrix([[0]]), matrix([[2]]))
>>> np.nonzero(goalmat == -1)
(matrix([[1, 1]]), matrix([[0, 2]]))
```

And

```
>>> goalmat = np.matrix( [[2, 2, 1], [-1, 1, -1]])
>>> goalmat
matrix([[ 2,  2,  1],
        [-1,  1, -1]])
>>> np.nonzero(goalmat == 1)
(matrix([[0, 1]]), matrix([[2, 1]]))
>>> np.nonzero(goalmat == -1)
(matrix([[1, 1]]), matrix([[0, 2]]))
```

So it seems to give the correct locations for 1 if I ask for -1...

Am I misusing/misunderstanding numpy.nonzero()?

Comment: That looks like the correct output to me... For each true location, you have a matrix of indices for axis 0 and a matrix of indices for axis 1.

Comment: You're right >___< I'll edit my question, have to find the correct data.

Comment: Sorry, I just took the wrong test runs from the shell, you were totally right. I fixed the question with the true weird results, at least I think they're weird :)

Comment: Oh man, okay, I get it. So (matrix([[1, 1]]), matrix([[0, 2]])) doesn't mean [1,1] and [0,2] but instead [1,0] and [1,2], right?

Duhhh, okay, I just misread the output and was confused. Thanks!

Comment: The docs show that taking the transpose produces the pairs you expected, ` np.transpose(np.nonzero(x))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work correctly and you actually did not use the `nonzero()` with values of -1 but with True and False being the output of the statement `goalmat == -1`.
You can check the `nonzero()` result by:

```
>>> index1, index2 = np.nonzero(goalmat == -1)
>>> goalmat[index1, index2]
matrix([[-1, -1]])
```